# Extract data from JS config object to create new object

Tags: javascript, foreach, configuration, lodash

Give this config object member (part of a larger object):

```
  stations: [
    {
      id: "RH",
      positions: ['RH2,', 'RH16', 'RH14']
    },
    {
      id: "WT",
      positions: ['WT10,', 'WT11', 'WT12', 'WT13', 'WT14', 'WT18']
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      positions: ['AO,', 'FF', 'PFF']
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      positions: ['AO,', 'FF', 'PFF']
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      positions: ['AO,', 'FF', 'PFF']
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      positions: ['AO,', 'FF', 'PFF']
    }
  ],
```

I need to iterate over it and generate this object for each object in the stations array:

```
var myObj = {
  "station": 1,
  "slots": [
    {
      "position": "AO" 
      "name": [name]
    },
    {
      "position": "FF" 
      "name": [name]
    },
    {
      "position": "PFF" 
      "name": [name]
    },
  ]  
}
```

I'll be filling in the name separately, so I'm not worried about that value at this point.

I've been trying to do this with lodash _.forEach(), but I have a feeling I'm not using it nearly as effectively as I could. What I'm trying to do (and failing at) is use a _.forEach() inside of another one, and I can't access the variables in the outer loop from the inner loop:

```
  this.shiftTables = [];
  _.forEach(stations, function(station) {
    var table = {
      "station": station.id,
      "slots": []
    };

    //Iterate over station.positions
    _.forEach(station.positions, function(position) {
      var slot = {
        "position": position,
        "name": "Name"
      };
    });

    vm.shiftTables.push(table);
  });
```

(this is just to show what I'm trying to do - not working code).

So how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is plain javascript solution with two `forEach()` loops.

```js
var data ={"stations":[{"id":"RH","positions":["RH2,","RH16","RH14"]},{"id":"WT","positions":["WT10,","WT11","WT12","WT13","WT14","WT18"]},{"id":1,"positions":["AO,","FF","PFF"]},{"id":2,"positions":["AO,","FF","PFF"]},{"id":3,"positions":["AO,","FF","PFF"]},{"id":4,"positions":["AO,","FF","PFF"]}]}

var result = [];

data.stations.forEach(function(o) {
  var obj = {station: o.id, slots: []}
  o.positions.forEach(function(e) {
    obj.slots.push({
      position: e,
      name: "Name"
    })
  })
  result.push(obj);
});

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```